# How can I use shmget to implement shared-memory in a Java application?

Tags: java, real-time, shared-memory, mmap, memory-mapped-files

Is there a good way, native through JNI or not, to do shared-memory in Java using `shmget`? I'm currently doing shared-memory through a memory mapped file, but I want to do it in a non-file way through `shmget`.

More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747838/is-it-possible-for-two-processes-to-use-the-same-shared-memory-without-resorting

Comment: OP mentioned using JNI to call shmget. Your comment does not apply. And chatgpt usage is banned in Stackoverlow:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned. Use your own content instead.

Comment: Pure way in what context? For Java most people would interpret that it means pure a Java solution without JNI. You should explain what problem are you trying to actually solve instead of skipping directly to a possible solution.

Comment: @aled I edited. Changed `pure way` to `non-file way`. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and why are Java memory mapped files are not adequate. Note that memory mapped is faster than normal files and managed by the OS.

Comment: @aled My friend, it is well explained. You are looking for hair on an eggshell. Please let other people take a shot instead of keep being negative. Of course I know what mmap files are. This is not my question. Please stop stating the obvious to mess with my question. Memory-mapped files have to be swapped in and out of disk. You understand there is a cost there, right? Do you think `shmget` exists just to annoy you? Anyway, I'm not answering any more of your comments. Peace!

Comment: You should be able to set this up with [Foreign Memory API and jextract](https://jdk.java.net/jextract/), various versions are available from JDK16 upwards but not that this incubating or preview status.

Comment: Why? What practical difference have you identified that would make `shmget()` better than a memory-mapped file?

Comment: @user207421 There is no _SWAPPING_ involved with `shmget()` as data does not have to be persisted to the memory-mapped file. `shmget()` exists to allow you to use shared-memory without the persistency penalty. Check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747838/is-it-possible-for-two-processes-to-use-the-same-shared-memory-without-resorting

Comment: @ThreadFrank understanding the context of the question is important. Consider it as a part of the "what has been tried". You may have excellent reasons but they need to be shared with readers. Questions should be as self-contained as possible. You should put all the information in the question, not with links to other questions or outside sites.

Comment: Thanks for schooling man. You are the best and one of the reasons why SO is such a friendly place!

Answer (score 2):

As DuncG suggested, you can use [java.lang.foreign](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/foreign/package-summary.html) to access C functions.  However, there are some caveats:

- As of Java 20, this is still a preview feature, which means public classes and their members may change, or may be removed entirely, in the next few Java releases.
- Compiling requires the compiler options `--enable-preview --release 20`.  I also recommend the `-Xlint:-preview` option.
- Running requires the Java command line options `--enable-preview --enable-native-access=com.example`.  Replace `com.example` with your module name, or replace it with `ALL-UNNAMED` if you are not declaring a module.

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.lang.foreign.Linker;
import java.lang.foreign.FunctionDescriptor;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout;
import java.lang.foreign.Arena;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;

import java.util.Objects;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class SHM {
    private static final boolean IS_64_BIT =
        System.getProperty("os.arch").contains("64");

    private static MemorySegment lookupFunction(String name) {
        return Linker.nativeLinker().defaultLookup().find(name).orElseThrow(
            () -> new RuntimeException("Function " + name + "() not found."));
    }

    private static MemorySegment lookupValue(String name) {
        return Linker.nativeLinker().defaultLookup().find(name).orElseThrow(
            () -> new RuntimeException("Value " + name + " not found."));
    }

    private static final MethodHandle strerror =
        Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(
            lookupFunction("strerror"),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(
                ValueLayout.ADDRESS,    // return
                ValueLayout.JAVA_INT)   // errnum
        );

    private static final MethodHandle shmget =
        Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(
            lookupFunction("shmget"),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(
                ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,       // return
                ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,       // key
                IS_64_BIT                   // size
                    ? ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG
                    : ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,
                ValueLayout.JAVA_INT)       // shmflg
        );

    private static final MethodHandle shmat =
        Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(
            lookupFunction("shmat"),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(
                ValueLayout.ADDRESS,        // return
                ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,       // shmid
                ValueLayout.JAVA_INT)       // shmflg
        );

    private static final MethodHandle shmdt =
        Linker.nativeLinker().downcallHandle(
            lookupFunction("shmdt"),
            FunctionDescriptor.of(
                ValueLayout.JAVA_INT,       // return
                ValueLayout.ADDRESS)        // shmaddr
        );

    private static String strerror(int errnum)
    throws IOException {
        MemorySegment message;
        try {
            message = (MemorySegment) strerror.invokeExact(errnum);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new IOException(t);
        }

        String messageStr;
        try (Arena arena = Arena.openConfined()) {
            // java.lang.foreign always returns memory addresses
            // as zero-length MemorySegments.
            MemorySegment bounded = MemorySegment.ofAddress(message.address(),
                4096, arena.scope());
            messageStr = bounded.getUtf8String(0);
        }

        return messageStr;
    }

    private static int errno()
    throws IOException {
        MemorySegment seg = lookupValue("errno");

        int num;
        try (Arena arena = Arena.openConfined()) {
            // java.lang.foreign always returns memory addresses
            // as zero-length MemorySegments.
            MemorySegment bounded = MemorySegment.ofAddress(seg.address(),
                Integer.BYTES, arena.scope());
            num = bounded.get(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, 0);
        }

        return num;
    }

    public void useSharedMemory(int shmKey,
                                int shmSize,
                                Consumer<ByteBuffer> task)
    throws IOException {

        if (shmSize < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot negative.");
        }
        Objects.requireNonNull(task, "Task cannot be null.");

        try (Arena arena = Arena.openConfined()) {
            int shmid;
            try {
                if (IS_64_BIT) {
                    shmid = (int) shmget.invokeExact(shmKey, (long) shmSize, 0);
                } else {
                    shmid = (int) shmget.invokeExact(shmKey, shmSize, 0);
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new IOException(t);
            }

            if (shmid == -1) {
                throw new IOException(
                    "shmget() returned " + shmid + ": " + strerror(errno()));
            }

            MemorySegment addr;
            try {
                addr = (MemorySegment) shmat.invokeExact(
                    shmid, MemorySegment.NULL, 0);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new IOException(t);
            }

            if (addr.address() == -1) {
                throw new IOException(
                    "shmat() returned " + addr.address() + ": "
                    + strerror(errno()));
            }

            // java.lang.foreign always returns memory addresses
            // as zero-length MemorySegments.
            MemorySegment boundedAddr =
                MemorySegment.ofAddress(addr.address(), shmSize, arena.scope());

            task.accept(boundedAddr.asByteBuffer());

            int status;
            try {
                status = (int) shmdt.invokeExact(addr);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                throw new IOException(t);
            }

            if (status != 0) {
                throw new IOException(
                    "shmdt() returned " + status + ": " + strerror(errno()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fair warning: I have only done minimal testing on the above code.

Comment: Thanks @VGR. I think at this point for a production grade system it is best to go with JNI. I was hoping that someone somewhere had already written a wrapper project for that. But I've searched everywhere and was not able to find it.

Comment: For what it’s worth, [this is the intended replacement for JNI.](https://openjdk.org/jeps/412)